# Store bakup files in tree like structure in AWS S3

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I running a batch file that take my mongo db backup and move to S3 bucket.I want store that backup in S3 like below structure.

**My Code:**

```
# DB host (secondary preferred as to avoid impacting primary performance)
HOST=db.example.com

# DB name
DBNAME=my-db

# S3 bucket name
BUCKET=s3-bucket-name

# Linux user account
USER=ubuntu

# Current time
TIME=`/bin/date +%d-%m-%Y-%T`

# Backup directory
DEST=/home/$USER/tmp

# Tar file of backup directory
TAR=$DEST/../$TIME.tar

# Create backup dir (-p to avoid warning if already exists)
/bin/mkdir -p $DEST

# Log
echo "Backing up $HOST/$DBNAME to s3://$BUCKET/ on $TIME";

# Dump from mongodb host into backup directory
/usr/bin/mongodump -h $HOST -d $DBNAME -o $DEST

# Create tar of backup directory
/bin/tar cvf $TAR -C $DEST .

# Upload tar to s3
/usr/bin/aws s3 cp $TAR s3://$BUCKET/

# Remove tar file locally
/bin/rm -f $TAR

# Remove backup directory
/bin/rm -rf $DEST

# All done
echo "Backup available at https://s3.amazonaws.com/$BUCKET/$TIME.tar"
```

**Structure:**

2020 -> may -> 20 -> file1

Any one help me to solve this.

Comment: What is wrong or deficient with the script you have written?

Comment: @jarmod While using this code , The files are just listed as of now. I need to organise files inside a specific folder. (path :    2020 -> may -> 20 -> file1 , file2,....)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to store it as `2020/05/20/file1` so that it sorts correctly (rather than including the *name* of the month).

You can use:

```
TIME=`/bin/date +%Y/%m/%d`
```

This will provide the value: `2020/05/20`

You can use that in the path of your output file.

See: [7 Linux Date Command Examples to Display and Set System Date Time](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/05/date-command-examples/)